# Itextsharp Alignments

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I'm working on a project that should generate a well organized report. I want to get the output like this;

```
 Reference No    : mp010
 Applied Vacancy : Helper
 ID No           : 200882318
```

But currently Im getting the output without the desired alignment. 
Eg;

```
 Reference No : mp010
 Applied Vacancy : Helper
 ID No : 200882318
```

I used *chunks* to print get the output. "other" means the  font type.

```
      Chunk refn = new Chunk("Reference No : " + refr + "", other);                       
      Chunk positn = new Chunk("Applied Vacancy : " + position + "", other);
      Chunk idno = new Chunk("ID No : " + id + "", other);
```

I'm very new to itextsharp and this is my first report. Please help me...

Comment: Why don't you use a `PdfPTable` or a TAB `Chunk`? For examples, read [The Best Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) (that's a free ebook with `PdfPTable` examples and an example on how to use Tabs).

Comment: I'll add an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you would achieve this using a `PdfPTable`:

```
PdfPTable third_table = new PdfPTable(2);
third_table.TotalWidth = 560f;
third_table.LockedWidth = true;
third_table.SetWidths(new float[] { 2.4f, 6.6f });

third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Responsibilities Held: ", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase( Responsibilities_held, other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });

third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description of Work Done:", other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });
third_table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase( Description_of_work_done, other)) { BorderWidth = 0 });

document.Add(third_table);
```

You can find more information about `PdfPTable` [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/86/itextsharp-introducing-tables) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-table-in-pdf-using-c-sharp-and-itextsharp).